# Django: Model.objects.get fails with ImportError exception

Tags: python, exception, django-models, importerror

I've model which represents settings in my system and I use it from another part of my application so that import has 3 levels `WORKING CODE <- Module <- Model`

Model `Variables`

```
from django.db import models

class Variables(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length = 20, verbose_name = 'Variable')
    value = models.CharField(max_length = 1024)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'core'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s: %s' % (self.key, self.value,)
```

Here is the code I'm using it from

Module `variables.py`

```
from core.models.storage import Variables

def get_var(name):
  return Variables.objects.get(key = name)
```

Module `config.py`

```
  var = get_var('some_key')
```

When I use this stuff from django shell everything works well but when I call `get_var` function I've `ImportError` exception

`storage.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Variables(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length = 20, verbose_name = 'Variable')
    value = models.CharField(max_length = 1024)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'core'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s: %s' % (self.key, self.value,)
```

```
  File "monitor_cli.py", line 19, in 
    print worker.get_provider()
  File "/home/sultan/Project/monitor/app/worker.py", line 14, in get_provider
    print Variables.objects.get(pk=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 132, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 341, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 550, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 568, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1172, in add_q
    can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1060, in add_filter
    negate=negate, process_extras=process_extras)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1226, in setup_joins
    field, model, direct, m2m = opts.get_field_by_name(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 307, in get_field_by_name
    cache = self.init_name_map()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 337, in init_name_map
    for f, model in self.get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 414, in get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model
    cache = self._fill_related_many_to_many_cache()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 428, in _fill_related_many_to_many_cache
    for klass in get_models():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 167, in get_models
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 61, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 76, in load_app
    app_module = import_module(app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named c
```

Comment: Can you please post the entirety of your models.py file? It probably has something to do with another part of the file. Try doing `from core.models import *` and see what happens.

Comment: Hang on. Do you have a models directory with files within it? Is there a reason you don't have a models.py file with all your models defined within that?

Comment: @Josh Smeaton yes I've models directory with model files

Comment: importing * from models works fine, but the same error

Comment: if I put in my code `Variables.objects.all()` it works well, but if     `Variables.objects.get(pk=1)` I get exception

Comment: review your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py I think there is an syntax error in one of applications

Comment: Show the entire storage.py file. There's probably a syntax error in there somewhere. `.all()` returns a queryset. You seem to be having trouble when using an instance of the Variable class.

Comment: Just added the sources of `storage.py`

Comment: now the same problem appear with any model when I use `filter` and `get` methods

Comment: you have an app in which there is a folder named models?Where are variables.py and config.py located?

Comment: Yes I have models folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the models directory, and put all your models in a models.py file, unless you have a VERY good reason not to. Change your imports to `from core.models import Variable` (rename your `Variables` class to `Variable` - django models should be named as the singular not the plural).

The problem probably has to do with the fact that your models live in namespaces other than `models`; ie. `models.storage`. The django infrastructure expects certain things to be in certain places. If you're going to put models in separate namespaces like you're doing, you should be importing them from the `__init__.py` file within the `models` module. Don't do this, again, unless you have a very good reason.

Finally, when asking questions of this nature, you should provide a lot more information. You should show the code of all of the relevant files. You should provide detail on what you've done that deviates from the convention of django (in this case, a models directory rather than a models.py file). You should also show relevant settings from `settings.py`, in this case, your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. You should also tell us what version of django and python you are using; this is sometimes relevant. More information upfront is much better than less information.

Comment: I have all the models in models.py. I am getting the same error (works for .all() but fails for .get(pk=1)).

Comment: What are issues if I have ten of models e.g. 20 and I need to separate them with separate files?

Comment: @sultan, you don't NEED to separate them into multiple files. For organizational purposes, you might WANT to. Understand the consequences of doing so first, without blindly doing it. Check the django source for examples (and look at the `__init__.py` file in the models directory if you do). Now that you have all your models in one file, delete the previous code examples from your question, and post the contents of models.py and your INSTALLED_APPS settings.

Comment: I've found the reason why the system failed this way, so I have external module `monitor` on the same level with my `core` application and I tried to use `core` application's models from within `monitor` app. Thats the stuff and I just had to register it in the `setting.py` under the `INSTALLED_APPS` @Josh Smeaton Thanks a lot